# Coffeescript binding?

Tags: coffeescript, bind

I just finished reading *The Little Book on Coffeescript*, and I'm trying to get my head around the language. I'm trying to figure out how to do quite a plain vanilla bind. Here's my code:

```
times = (a = 1, b = 2) -> a*b 
h  = alert.bind times 8, 9    
h
```

This doesn't produce any errors but it also doesn't run any alerts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you think this does?

Comment: You __are__ getting an error in the resulting JavaScript, `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

Comment: @Mathletics No, you only get the error if you invoke the function.

Comment: @RoyJ both of our answers point out that OP needs to invoke the function, whereupon they will see this error. If you want to be really pedantic, sure, this code produces no errors because _it doesn't do anything._ A corrected version of the code will throw the error.

Comment: @Mathletics But to say that the OP *is* getting an error is not true. The OP isn't. We are, when we change his code. A corrected version of the code will do exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helpful tool for understanding coffeescript is [JS2Coffee](http://js2.coffee/), which will translate code back and forth between Coffeescript and JavaScript. Then you can see whether what you've written is what you thought you wrote.

Your code here has two issues:

1. `bind` takes a context (which it will use as its `this`) as its first argument. Subsequent arguments will form the arguments list of the bound function when the new function is invoked.
2. Invoking a function that has no parameters requires parentheses in CS

Comment: thanks a lot. much appreciated and great to see there's such an active and well-cinformed cs user base on so.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're not invoking the function `h`. You need to call `h()`.
2. This code doesn't make sense. Line 2 transpiles to `var h = alert.bind(times(8, 9))` meaning you are trying to create a version of `alert` where `this` is `72`. ??? You can't do that.
3. Per 2, this throws an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`.